# Mysql treat column value as a regex for select

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

is it possible to query a result depending on the regex pattern of a column?

assuming i have 2 tables

```
table A
legs     fur                name
4        red                 cat
4        blue || spots       dog
1                            dolphin
1        black               shark
1        yellow              shark
1        white|| black       whale
2        [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}   exp1
2        [0-9]{4}            expA-1


table B
cageNumber   weight      legs     fur
192910       26          4        red
332192       12          1        black
119199       32          4        blue
111000       19          4        spots
192991       11          4        green
000001       14          2        0913-11        
000002       11          2        1102      
000003       16          2
```

what I need to do is to have a select statement which describes cage number and name depending on fur color

```
cageNumber name
192910     cat
332192     shark
111000     dog
119199     dog
192991     null
000001     exp1
000002     expA-1
000003     null
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Why doesn't `332192` match `shark`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `blue || spots` to `blue|spots` to make it a correct regular expression.

Then this should work:

```
ON B.fur REGEXP CONCAT('^(', A.fur, ')$')
```

I added `^` and `$` in order to anchor to the ends.  That way, `blue` will match, but `blueblood` will not.

I added `(` and `)` so that `blue|sports` would match only `blue` and `sports`, not `blueblood` and `teamsports`.  Think about what happens with `^blue|sports$` -- that means "start with blue or end with sports".

Comment: this is noted, Assuming this is working - is it possible to add a regex that test string patterns? eg. 3 digit 0-5 numbers only or [0-5]{3}

Comment: @Led - `[0-5]{3}` matches 3 adjacent digits anywhere in the string; they are limited to 6 different digits (0..5).  `000` matches, but so does `90009` and even `00000000`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, look at my little example. It delivers only expertId=1, contingentId=59 and description starts with ## followed by a number.

```
select * from entry where expert_id=1 and contingent_id=59 and (description REGEXP '^##[0-9]');
```

Comment: can you make a sample querry

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.cageNumber, A.name FROM A JOIN B ON B.fur LIKE A.fur;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use join with like

```
SELECT b.id, a.initiatorWallet FROM ledTest a
INNER JOIN ledTestB b ON a.transtype = b.transType
WHERE b.wallet RLIKE ( a.regex)
```

Comment: @Led please check this one

Comment: is this applicable to number regex pattern too?  like [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}  or   [0-9]{4}

Comment: Yes  try using LIKE  '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2} or [0-9]{4}'

Comment: thank you very much, as of now this is the accepted answer (will check when I go back to the office tomorrow)

Comment: Sure let me know you you still face the issue

Comment: No -- `LIKE` only handles _two_ wild cards:  `%` and `_`; it does not understand `[0-9]` etc.

Comment: We can use `RLIKE` for matching the patern search

Comment: hi nishant, it doesnt work. Here is my sql file https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aj3mZJyvonztzaEm6LbG9RlUnOFtGa19w8kUHPCid4I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i believe you only have view access :)